# Displaying images in a Recyclerview

Tags: android, image, android-glide, fresco

I have a recyclerview that I want to display images that I have saved in drawables in jpeg. For loading I was using an Async Task, but this doesn't preload or Cache them. I was told to use one of the tools like fresco or glide to do that, but which one can do the Job better?

The most important thing for me is that the app doesn't crash, but it would also be nice to be able to preload certain images already before the View is displayed and afterwards preload as many as memory allows.

Comment: use Glide/NetworkImageView of Volley/Univesal Image Loader

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fresco for this. An example for a recycler view that loads images from the network can be found here:

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/drawee/DraweeRecyclerViewFragment.java